# Can I communicate with a STM32 over SWO?

Tags: stm32, raspberry-pi

Currently, I can program/debug a STM32 over a Raspberry Pi 3 with **OpenOCD** and also want to receive and transmit data to/from STM32.

Can I use STM's **SWO** trace pin to transmit and receive data? Or is SWO only for debug purposes (read-only)?

Comment: depends on the chip but the SWD pins are just gpio pins so if you are not using them for SWD then they are fair game.   You cant use the SWD interface though if that is what you are after, you can examine the other alternate functions or bit bang with that pin and others.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the pin is self explanatory I think. SINGLE WIRE OUTPUT. It is for the debugging purposes, uses very specific transmission and programming methods.

I do not understand what for. You have plenty other interfaces available. You can use SPI (as my Universal Plus HATS - https://www.diymat.co.uk/product/universal-plus-hat-raspberry-pi/), I2C, U(S)ART, USB, CAN .....

Comment: I am trying to avoid any other interfaces (SPI, I2C, UART vs.) for simplicity and a challange for my self to understand deeper. I am using HAL libraries to program the stm32 and printing debug info with `ITM_SendChar()`funtion. While going through the hal libraries I also encountered `ITM_ReceiveChar()` function which made me think that, I can also receive data from SWO.

Comment: @pmundt You do not try to understand deeper. How can you try understand deeper and use the HAL libraries? If you want to understand deeper use the bare registers and control your hardware directly. SWO is dedicated for the debug purposes. If you took the ARM documentation instead of browsing the HAL, you would already understand why.

Comment: Then, I will start learning more about bare metal coding. Thank you very much for pointing out.